# AWX- provide response file

Tags: ansible, ansible-awx

I have a project using playbook to exec shell command as following:

```
/tmp/fileforinst.bin -varfile response.varfile
```

While I exec the shell command I provide `response.varfile` for installation purpose that includes some entries like target installation directory, app port, etc... The `response.varfile` format is like:

```
app.Home=/app/home
httpPort=8080
```

Currently I get the following error

> "Could not find or access 'runner/project/response.varfile' on the Ansible Controller"

The reason why I get the error is clear for me. The required `response.varfile` file exist in GIT sever on same branch as yml file (playbook)

Any idea how can I provide `response.varfile` file while I exec the shell command ?

Thank you

Comment: `The reason why I get the error is clear for me` <= Good, because it isn't for me at least. You only give a command your run out of nowhere without any context related to ansible. This command is, I suppose, run on a target and will look for your file there, not on the controller. So I guess the error you are reporting has nothing to do with the shell task you are talking about but don't give a single clue of what it looks like. Please make thie [mcve](/help/mcve). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> The required `response.varfile` file exist in Git sever on same branch as YML file (playbook)

Assuming you have a somehow similar structure in your Git repository for your role

```
tree APP/
├── files
├── main.yml
├── README.md
├── tasks
│   └── install_app.yml
└── templates
    └── response.file.j2
```

importing the [Project](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/userguide/projects.html) from Git into your Ansible AWX/Tower, than, the file is just available via the `templates` or `files` path.

```yaml
- name: Download installer from binary repository
  get_url:
    url: "https://{{ REPOSITORY_URL }}/Packages/{{ INSTALLER_FILE }}"
    url_username: "{{ API_USER }}"
    url_password: "{{ API_KEY }}"
    dest: "/opt/app"
    owner: "{{ APP_USER }}"
    group: "{{ APP_GROUP }}"
    mode: 0750

- name: Copy response file for unattended installation
  template:
    src: "response.file.j2"
    dest: "/opt/app/response.file"
    owner: "{{ APP_USER }}"
    group: "{{ APP_GROUP }}"
    mode: 0750

- name: Install App
  shell: 
    cmd: "/opt/app/{{ INSTALLER_FILE }} -q -varfile /opt/app/response.file"
  register: install_result

- name: Show install result
  debug: 
    msg: "{{ install_result.stdout_lines }}"
```

This is almost what I am using in my production environment to install and update the "App". In words, you have to copy the file over form Ansible Control Node to the Remote Node where the installation shall happen.

**Further reading**

- [Template a file out to a target host](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/template_module.html)
- [Directory layout](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/user_guide/playbooks_best_practices.html#directory-layout)

Comment: thank you. I just have to comment out the line with lookup that worked while using playbook without run it thru AWX
` - name: copy response.varfile to remote host
        copy:
    #      src: "{{ lookup('env', 'PWD') }}/response.varfile"
          src: "response.varfile" 
          dest: /tmp
    #      remote_src: true`